# Launching Multiple Browser and running the URL's

Tags: browser

```
    Protractor Version: 5.1.1
    NPM : 3.10.10`
    Browsers:Microsoft Edge(Ver 14), Safari(Ver 5.1.7), IE Ver11.0, firefox(ver 46.0) and Opera(Ver 43.0) Ver11.0, firefox(ver 46.0) and O: Win 10 43.0)
    Operating System and Version : Win 10
    Conf.js
    //Code changes for multiCapabilities
    multiCapabilities: [
    {
    browserName: 'chrome',



     },
     {
       browserName: 'firefox',

    },
    {
    browserName: 'MicrosoftEdge',
    },
    {
    browserName: 'Opera',
    },
    {
    browserName: 'Internet Explorer',
    },
    {
    browserName: 'safari',
    }, ],

    Protractor.js

    'webDriverUpdate': {
    'browsers': ['chrome']
    },
    'webDriverUpdate': {
    'browsers': ['Microsoft Edge']
    },
    'webDriverUpdate': {
    'browsers': ['safari']
    },

          'webDriverUpdate': {
            'browsers': ['Internet Explorer']
          },
          'webDriverUpdate': {
            'browsers': ['firefox']
          },
          'webDriverUpdate': {
            'browsers': ['Opera']
          },
          'webDriverStart': {
          'args': ['--chrome']
      },
                    'webDriverStart': {
                    'args': ['--Microsoft Edge']
                },
                'webDriverStart': {
                  'args': ['--Opera']

            },
            'webDriverStart': {
               'args': ['--safari']
            },
          'webDriverStart': {
              'args': ['--Internet Explorer']
          },
          'webDriverStart': {
              'args': ['--firefox']
          },
```

1. Issue: It is unable to launch Firefox,Safari,Microsoft Edge and Internet explorer though the drivers are downloaded in specific path
   based on the browser versions.
2. The following is the error message which is throwing in the console for all the browser

   Error message

> \node_modules\gulp-angular-protractor\node_modules\gulp-protractor\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\atoms\error.js:108
>       var template = new Error(this.message);
>       ^
>       UnknownError: The best matching driver provider org.openqa.selenium.edge.EdgeDriver can't create a new driver instance
>   for Capabilities [{count=1, browserName=Microsoft Edge

3. When I run the scripts using single browsers the same error message is getting displayed.

Comment: please add some words before the code

Comment: and please format your code properly so that it is readable...